# Executable file not found in $PATH: unknown. Как исправить?

Tags: golang, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Всем привет!

Dockerfile

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Base image
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM golang:1.21-bullseye AS golang_base
ENV USER=nonroot
ENV GROUP=nonroot
ENV UID=1000
ENV GID=1000
ENV GO111MODULE="on"
ENV GOOS=linux
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN go mod tidy
RUN addgroup --gid="${GID}" ${GROUP}
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    --ingroup "${GROUP}" \
    "${USER}"

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Test image
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM golang_base AS golang_test
ENV GO111MODULE="on"
ENV GOOS=linux
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir -m 777 /var/www
CMD go test ./...


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build image
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM golang_base AS golang_build
ENV GO111MODULE="on"
ENV GOOS=linux
RUN mkdir -m 777 /nonexistent
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git protobuf-compiler golang-goprotobuf-dev
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir -m 777 /var/www
RUN go build -o /var/www/server /app/cmd/main.go
RUN chmod +x /var/www/server
RUN go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.27
RUN go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.2


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Development image
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM golang_build AS golang_dev
ENV APP_PORT=8080
ENV USER=nonroot
USER ${USER}
VOLUME /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE ${APP_PORT}
CMD go run /app/cmd/main.go


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Production image
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM alpine:3.7 AS golang_prod
ENV APP_PORT=8080
ENV USER=nonroot
COPY --from=golang_base /etc/passwd /etc/passwd
COPY --from=golang_build /var/www/server /var/www/server
RUN chmod 755 /var/www/server
RUN chown ${USER} /var/www/server
RUN chmod a+x /var/www/server
USER ${USER}
WORKDIR /var/www
EXPOSE ${APP_PORT}
CMD ["server"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  database:

services:
  database: &database
    container_name: database
    image: postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "${POSTGRES_DB}", "-U", "${POSTGRES_USER}" ]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 2s
      retries: 10
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT_EXTERNAL}:${POSTGRES_PORT}
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
    volumes:
      - profile-database:/var/lib/postgresql/data:delegated
    networks:
      - database
  prod:
    container_name: profile
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./build/dockerfiles/golang/Dockerfile
      target: golang_prod
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=database
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - ${GRPC_PORT}:${GRPC_PORT}
      - "40000:40000"
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - database

volumes:
  profile-database: { }
```

запускаю

```
docker-compose run --rm prod
```

выдает

```
docker-compose run --rm prod
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              docker:default
[+] Creating 1/0
 ✔ Container database  Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              docker:default 
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "server": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Прошу помогите.
Как исправить?

---

UPD:

приложение  - это service профилей на grpc

https://github.com/3110Y/cc-profile/tree/init

UDP2:

даже такое приложение вызывает такую ошибку

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hhhh")
}
```

Comment: Опишите работу кода. Что он должен делать?

Comment: https://github.com/3110Y/cc-profile/tree/init

Comment: service профилей на grpc

Comment: В текст вопроса вставьте описание, чтоб читать было удобно.

Comment: `/var/www` не в переменной `PATH`. Поэтому запускайте сервер по полному пути `/var/www/server`

Comment: Тогда выдает ```exec /var/www/server: no such file or directory```

Comment: Хотя файл есть.

Comment: И правильно пишет. Вы собираете приложение в образе bullseye, то есть он линкуется с glibc. А запускаете в alpine, где нет glibc. При запуске в alpine не находится libc.so.6, о чем вам сообщает file not found :) Измените либо образ для сборки на go:x.y.z-alpine, либо образ для запуска на debian:bullseye.

Comment: спасибо. все сработало